# The program is showing null pointer exception....converting double to int

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

My program causes a null pointer exception... I think the problem is in converting lat3 and lon3 from double to int... Is there some other way of parsing the location in double to int to give it to GeoPoint?

Code:

```
public class mapLoc extends com.google.android.maps.MapActivity implements LocationListener
{
    TextView t ;
    int lat2,lon2,lat3,lon3;
    Double presentlon,presentlat;

    Drawable d;
    MapView mv;
    MapController mc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.maptxt);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();

     String latitude = extra.getString("latitude");
     String longitude = extra.getString("longitude");

     t.append(latitude+"\t");
     t.append(longitude);
     Float lat1 = Float.parseFloat(latitude);
     Float lon1 = Float.parseFloat(longitude);
        lat2 = (int) (lat1*1E6);   
        lon2 = (int) (lon1*1E6); 


        mv = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.maps);

        mc = mv.getController();
        mc.setZoom(14);
        mv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mv.displayZoomControls(true);
        mv.setClickable(true);


     List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mv.getOverlays();
     Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
     overlay itemizedoverlay = new overlay(drawable, this);

     lat3 = (int)(presentlat * 1E6);
     lon3 = (int)(presentlon * 1E6);


     GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat3, lon3);

     OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello, user", "This is your present location");
     mc.animateTo(point);

     itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
     mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

     GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(lat2, lon2);
     OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "This is your","saved location");
     itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
     mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);



    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
     presentlat = location.getLatitude();
     presentlon =  location.getLongitude();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    };



}
```

Logcat errors:

```
05-25 10:21:52.444: W/dalvikvm(342): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-25 10:21:52.444: E/AndroidRuntime(342): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.loc/com.loc.mapLoc}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at com.loc.mapLoc.onCreate(mapLoc.java:71)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-25 10:21:52.454: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code snippet I dont think these presentlat  and presentlon  are getting initialized and hence throwing NPE.

```
 lat3 = (int)(presentlat * 1E6); // NPE
 lon3 = (int)(presentlon * 1E6);
```

Either initialize them before use or have a null check.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `Double` (capital D) is not a primitive type, but a reference type that happens to be able to hold only boxed `double` (note the difference) values - or `null`. The Java language doesn't treat unboxing differently than other object accesses through a reference. If the reference is `null` (which obviously is the case here), it'll throw a NPE. The real difference with unboxing is that such access happens implicitly through something like `ref.doubleValue()` when you use the reference in arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, your app is blowing up because presentlat and presentlon are private variables that have not been initialised. You should move that code into your onLocationChanged function.